# How do I set up a VPN on WIndows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn

I have searched all over the Internet and used several walk-throughs on how to set up VPN on Windows Server 2008 R2. I still cannot seem to get this to work properly. Can someone please point me toward some documentation that shows exactly how to set up the VPN correctly? I need information on what roles/services need to be implemented on the server, the settings that need to be changed on my firewall, and the settings that need to be used when setting up the VPN connection on the clients. I know there are several different protocols that can be used, I am willing to use any one that is secure. If you can provide setup information for a particular protocol that would be great. I have researched all of the different protocols, so I do not need a detailed explanation of each protocol.

As I said before, I have tried several different walk-throughs online, but I cannot seem to get this to work. If there are any common problems that happen during the VPN installation that could be an issue, could you please advise?

---

Additional Information:

I have a static IP on my modem. I can either use port forwarding or 1 to 1 NAT. I also have other static IP's available if necessary.

I know it is not always recommended, but I have this server running as a domain controller too. The server has 2 NIC's.

I am working on the server remotely through a VNC equivalent.

The modem/router/firewall (combo unit) is handing out DHCP, and I would like to keep it that way. I only need the VPN server to hand out 5 - 10 IP addresses. If those need to be set up static instead, that is fine.

---

Finally, thank you for your help. I know this might seem like an easy question, but I am pretty new to sys admin type stuff and am trying to educate myself.

Comment: Which VPN software will you be using?

Comment: The VPN Software that comes included in Win2K8. I believe it is in the Routing and Remote Access role.

Comment: The first thing to do is to add the Network Policy and Access Services role, of which RRAS is a component.

Comment: Why does this keep getting down voted? Is is really that bad of a question?

Comment: Lots of haters and egomaniacs around here - they know who they are and it's not too hard to spot them from their very unprofessional comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Technet has specific information for Windows Server 2008 R2.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725734%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Add a role, using Add Roles Wizard:

Initial Configuration Tasks window:
   Customize This Server:
       Add roles. 
          add Network Policy and Access Services role.  Next twice.
In NPAS Role services list, select Routing and Remote Access Services.

After installing it right click on the service RRAS node in the server manager, and configure it, you will probably want either the NAT+VPN mode, or just the VPN mode.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guide which should address most of what you appear to be seeking. It is not specific to 2008R2, but the steps are similar across the different versions of Windows.

http://practicallynetworked.com/security/set-up-a-personal-windows-vpn.htm

Comment: This is very good info for Windows 2003 level GUIs but the GUI for 2008 R2 is much different.